# Google.GData.Client read email

Tags: c#, gmail, feed, atom-feed

I'm using Google's .NET Client Library to read email on my gmail account.

But things are not very clear for me.

I'm trying to retrieve Atom feeds with this code.

```
FeedQuery query = new FeedQuery();
Service service = new Service("mail", "app-MailChecker-1");
service.setUserCredentials(Username, Password);
query.Uri = new Uri("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom");
AtomFeed feed = service.Query(query);
```

It gives me a simple exception: can't retrieve feed.

My priority is to accomplish this using Google's .NET Client Library
but other options will be helpful as well.

Additional information: this method works for Google Calendar without a problem.

Comment: Try reading this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989986/reading-atom-feed-of-gmail-account-from-c][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989986/reading-atom-feed-of-gmail-account-from-c

Comment: I checked that already.
I'll wait for Google .NET client library solution for some time.
thanks anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read Google's FAQ about the Google Data Protocol you'll see that it has no data API for GMail.

http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/gdata/faq.html#GmailAtomFeed

To quote:

> Does Gmail have a Data API?
>
> No, but you can use Gmail's Atom feed with AuthSub or OAuth to request
>   read-only access to a user's unread messages. The scope should be set
>   to https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/. An example query would be:
>
> GET https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/
>
> If you're interested in managing your mail, Gmail also has IMAP/POP
>   support.

I experimented with version 1.9.0.0 of the Google Data .NET Client Library myself. Don't see any references to GMail.

Here's one possible approach on how to retrieve the unread messages:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=292

It's similar to what Christian suggested in his comment.

Comment: thanks you
i already implemented another solution something like that (solution you provided)